# How to have mdfind search system and library files

Tags: spotlight, search

I need to write a script for many users to find where some other dependencies maybe installed. I would like to use mdfind for the Mac users to search in their /opt or /usr directories, but it seems mdfind (and Spotlight) don't search system and library files.

Is there some way to force it to search there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to clarify - I want mdfind to search the /opt and /usr directories. It does not by default.